# User wants me to upvote their question

Tags: discussion

Recently I answered a question which the user thought was good, and accepted. They then told me "can u up my question?". I don't want to violate any rules, but I also don't want to hurt the user's feelings.

**How do I go about this?**

Comment: Answer to similar thread at [metaso]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323849/2261442

Answer (score 25):

Upvoting a question means you find it interesting or useful, that it shows research effort and is clear. Most of the times, if a question is interesting enough for you to take the time to answer it, it is good enough to be upvoted. Not always, but usually.

There are no rules that can be broken by upvoting a question, so I don't know what rules you're thinking of. In any case, don't worry, upvote any post you find useful freely, you won't be breaking any rules.

Now, in the specific [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333118/22222) you are referring to, you suggested to the OP that they might want to accept your answer (which is fine, when done politely as you did) and they answered with a request to upvote their question. This is not quite the same as the OP asking you for an upvote out of the blue. I'm not saying it's OK—asking for votes is never a useful comment, even asking for accepts is borderline—but there was more context to the OP's request.

So, the best response to that comment would be, as @muru [suggested](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4298/22222), to flag it as "not constructive", which it is. However, you should indeed also seriously consider voting on the post. The basic message here is that you should upvote whenever you feel a question or answer deserves an upvote and you should downvote whenever youl feel a question or answer deserves a downvote. That's the way the site works and both up and downvotes are essential as they help separate the bad posts from the good. I notice that you have been a member of the site for 5 months and yet have cast a total of 3 votes! Please start voting more often. Votes are essential to the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: Huh, so it was case of accepts for up votes? That's beyond not OK, that's veering into shenanigans territory, depending on how often it happens

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the comment. Upvote if the post is worthy of upvoting by whatever standards you usually use.

Maybe flag the comment as not constructive. That's what I would do. And probably downvote to boot. >:)

Comment: No, do *not* downvote a question based on a comment that bothered you. That's childish and petty. You should vote based on the question's quality and nothing else.

Comment: @terdon or its Pavlovian training

Comment: No, it is revenge voting and it's not cool.

Comment: @terdon revenge for what? O.o

Comment: You are suggesting that the OP should downvote the question because of a comment they object to. Not because anything is wrong with the Q but because they (or you) don't like the behavior of the question's OP. That is called revenge voting and is not welcome behavior here. I know (or hope) that you were only joking but since this is a meta answer, I wanted to make it very clear that votes should only be cast based on the post, and not on the OP's behavior.

Comment: @terdon oh, it's a joke alright; hence the smiley